# How to group and order mysqli query from 50 million records to load faster?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database which consists of 50 million records and I am trying to execute the following query.

```
SELECT q FROM q GROUP BY q ORDER BY t DESC LIMIT 100;
```

But, because of the size of the database, this query takes about 10 seconds to execute. So, how do I optimize this query for faster execution? 
[How does database indexing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work)
I referred to this page for an answer, it suggests to use indexing but doesn't exactly tell how? I am new to this, I need a quick solution to this problem as my site is loading very slow.

Comment: ALTER TABLE `dbName`.`tableName` DROP INDEX `newKeyName`, ADD INDEX `newKeyName` (`q`) USING BTREE;

Answer (score 1):

By this way you can create Index.

```
Alter table q
add key(q),
add key(t);
```